# Mongoexport csv - print timestamp of the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I need the created timestamp of the document in a csv along with other fields. How do I get that using mongo export?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoexport` doesn't allow transformations on the collection that you're exporting, so you'll want to take the exported CSV and use another tool to convert the [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) into a date. Here's an example of a super ugly shell script to do that:

```sh
...get objectId \
 | sed -E 's|([0-9a-f]{8}).+|\1|' \
 | xargs -I {} echo '$((16#'{}"))" \
 | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo {}" \
 | xargs -I {} date -d @{}
```

- `sed` -- grab first 8 characters of the ObjectId
- `$((16#{}))` -- convert those 8 characters into decimal
- `date -d @{}` -- convert seconds into a date

An alternative to all this would be using the mongo aggregation framework to get the timestamps from the ObjectIds and then use the `$out` command to save the updated fields into a new collection that you could then `mongoexport` from.

Comment: I'd love any advice about cleaning up that bash script -- I'm not very good with bash, and I had a hard time firguring out how to convert hex to decimal in a nice way